# Update or Insert data with an if else statement

Tags: php

Using one form. Trying to let user either INSERT or UPDAT the database.

Tried var_dump(); tried error_reporting(E_ALL);

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if (isset($_POST['text']))
{
    if ($result->num_rows)
        $text = ($_POST['text']);
    $birthday = ($_POST['birthday']);
    $gender= ($_GET['gender']);

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE profiles SET
    user=?, text=?, birthday=?, gender=?
    WHERE user=?");

    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $user, $text, $birthday, $gender);

/* execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();
}
//using bound paramaters for profile
else
{
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO profiles
    (user, text, birthday, gender)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $user, $text, $birthday, $gender);

/* execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();

/* close statement and connection */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Did receive undefined variable on gender (a radio button), but that went away. Data does not insert into database. Sometimes I see null in columns.

Comment: Why don't you use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` instead of 3 queries?

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about this. Perhaps, I should read up.

Comment: Can you use the DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with prepared statements?

Comment: Of course you can. See how I did it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UPDATE` query has 5 placeholders, but you only bind 4 parameters in `bind_param`. You need another `$user` at the end.

```
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE profiles SET
    user=?, text=?, birthday=?, gender=?
    WHERE user=?");

    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $user, $text, $birthday, $gender, $user);
```

But there's no need to set `user`, since you're just setting it to the same value, so change it to:

```
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE profiles SET
    text=?, birthday=?, gender=?
    WHERE user=?");

    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $text, $birthday, $gender, $user);
```

If the `user` column is a unique key, you can combine all your code into a single query, using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("
    INSERT INTO profiles (user, text, birthday, gender)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE text = VALUES(text), birthday = VALUES(birthday), gender = VALUES(gender)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $user, $texxt, $birthday, $gender);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement is missing it's brackets, and a few other mistakes other than what @Barmar mentioned.  I suggest looking into the the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement after you have figured out exactly why your code isn't working.

One of the more glaring reason why you were getting `null` values inserted into your table, is because you were setting the variables `$text`, `$birthday`, `$gender` in first half of your `if` statement, which will not be executed and will be uninitialized variables and all be equal to `null` after the `else`.

If you code is not outputting any errors, use the echo, or print function to give yourself an idea of where your code has reached, which will let you know where it stopped working.  You can also use php debugging plugins with your IDE of choice which should help you solve your issues a lot faster.

Here is a version of your code with a few fixes and adjustments.  Take the time to see exactly what @Barmar mentioned, and make sure you add brackets to all your if statements, even the one line ones, that way you don't confuse yourself while learning.

```
/** Did the user give us a name to use?  If not, resubmit the form with a user name */
if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $user     = $_POST['user'];     /** Remember to Sanitize & Validate Structure of User Inputs */
    $text     = $_POST['text'];     /** Remember to Sanitize & Validate Structure of User Inputs */
    $birthday = $_POST['birthday']; /** Remember to Sanitize & Validate Structure of User Inputs */
    $gender   = $_POST['gender'];   /** Remember to Sanitize & Validate Structure of User Inputs  */

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
    /* execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows)
    {
        $stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE profiles SET
            text=?, birthday=?, gender=?
            WHERE user=?");

        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $text, $birthday, $gender, $user);

        /* execute prepared statement */
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $stmt->error;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //using bound paramaters for profile
        $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO profiles
            (user, text, birthday, gender)
            VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $user, $text, $birthday, $gender);

        /* execute prepared statement */
        $stmt->execute();
     }

    /* close statement and connection */
    $stmt->close();
}
else
{
    echo "No User Inputs - Go ahead and submit the form";
}
```